# (Basic properties of order for natural numbers) Proofs

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Currently, I am self-studying Terence Tao's Analysis. I proves several of exercises but encountered difficulties with the others. Could you please check my proofs and suggest the solution for the remaining ones ? This is the proposition that we need to prove.

> **Proposition 2.2.12 (Basic properties of order for natural numbers).**
>   Proposition 2.2.12 (Basic properties of order for natural numbers).
>   Let a, b, c be natural numbers. Then
>
> - (a) (Order is reflexive) a ≥ a.
> - (b) (Order is transitive) If a ≥ b and b ≥ c, then a ≥ c.
> - (c) (Order is anti-symmetric) If a ≥ b and b ≥ a, then a = b.
> - (d) (Addition preserves order ) a ≥ b if and only if a + c ≥ b + c.
> - (e) a < b if and only if a++ ≤ b.
> - (f ) a < b if and only if b = a + d for some positive number d.

Tao gives the following definition.

> **Definition 2.2.11 (Ordering of the natural numbers).** Let n and m be
>   natural numbers. We say that n is greater than or equal to m, and
>   write n ≥ m or m ≤ n, iff we have n = m + a for some natural number a.
>   We say that n is strictly greater than m, and write n>m or m

I have the proofs for the first three statements. Could you please check it.

- > a) a $\ge$ a
  >   Proof: if a$\ge$ a, then a = a + n for some natural n. This is true for n = 0.
- > b) a $\ge$ b and b $\ge$ c, then a $\ge$ c
  >   Proof: From the antecedent, a = b + n and b = c + m, for some natural n,m   Then a =
  >   c + (n + m). Hence, a $\ge$ c
- > c) If a $\ge$ b and b $\ge$ a, then a = b
  >   Proof: Antecedent implies
  >   that a = b + n and b = a + m for some natural n, m.   Hence a = a + m
  >   n which is only true for n, m = 0.

I have doubts regarding the last proof since I have not used Peano axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two proofs look good.  The first is a little sloppy.

> a) a ≥ a
>
> Proof: if a≥ a, then a = a + n for some natural n. This is true for n = 0.

You can't start with “**if** $a \geq a$” if you want to show **that** $a \geq a$ is true.  So instead say: “Since $a = a+0$ and $0$ is a natural number, $a \geq a$.“